# Why is buffet and/or stall more likely to occur in a thunderstorm?

Tags: extreme-weather, principles-of-flight

the correct answer for this Q is:
"Because in a thunderstorm the speed of the aeroplane for a given power setting decreases, and the stall speed increases"
I would like to know why in a thunderstorm speed of the airplane decreases and why stall speed increases.
Appreciate all the answers

Comment: That sounds like a poorly written exam question and answer. Can you provide the source?

Comment: Yes, the answer is poorly worded, but perhaps the others are worse.  If you list the other choices we could perhaps help you understand why you can rule them out.  Sometimes the “least incorrect” is the only option.

Comment: That's an ***atrociously*** badly written answer... speed and stall speed can ***vary*** quite a bit in a thunderstorm, but to say that the one decreases & the other increases, is just wrong.  VTC because we're not here to explain the intent behind somebody's badly written testing materials.

Answer (score 3):

This is a strange question and answer. (It would be great if you could post a link to or citation for this "question" and "answer.")

First of all... don't fly in thunderstorms!

If caught in a thunderstorm, there are some considerations that might shed some light on this "answer," but they're related only in the sense that they happen to use some of the same words and phrases...

Airspeed: while executing the trusty [180-degree-turn](https://airfactsjournal.com/2020/06/the-180-degree-turn-a-life-saving-maneuver-for-all-pilots-even-test-pilots/) (turn around and get out of the storm!), the pilot would want to [slow down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maneuvering_speed) to reduce aerodynamic stress on the airframe in the heavy turbulence that can be expected in a thunderstorm. But it's the pilot who does does, by reducing power; not the storm.

Stall: thunderstorms tend to feature both turbulence and significant [wind shear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_shear). Both can cause increased load factor, and stall speed increases at higher load factors (equivalently, the shifting angle of attack may reach the critical angle even if you're above stall speed for level flight). In layman's terms: getting bumped and jolted around a lot can cause a stall.

I don't see that the stated question or answer really grasp these concepts, so I'm not sure this really answers the question. But it's the best I can come up with.

Comment: Question is from my ATPL(A) course